# count_posts to a standalone link

Tags: posts, count

I need to add the post count to a standalone link in my sidebar.
Just a custom link in the textfield widget, "All posts". 
How can i add a count of all published posts to it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`wp_count_posts`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_count_posts/)

**Example using code above:**

```
$count_posts = wp_count_posts('post');

if ( $count_posts ) {
    $published_posts = $count_posts->publish;
}

<a href="YOUR_LINK">YOUR TEXT <?php echo $published_posts; ?></a>
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark as correct answer and upvote :)

Comment: Thanks, @Tunjs Ayoola.

Still doesn't work.
This link is in the text widget in my sidebar.
Here's what i have exactly, all in one place^
`<?php 
$count_posts = wp_count_posts();
if ( $count_posts ) {
$published_posts = $count_posts->publish;
}
?> 

<a href="www.example.com" class="all_cats">All Posts <?php echo $published_posts; ?></a>`

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you counting the standard posts, pages or a custom post_type?

Comment: I need to count all the standard published posts of the blog. Not pages, nor anything else. Just all published posts.

Comment: what do you get when you `var_dump( $count_posts )`

Comment: I don't get you. What is `var_dump( $count_posts )`?

Comment: you should put `var_dump( $count_posts );` after the `$count_posts` then paste the output here